# How do we call a tendency of young children to accept things as facts without doubting them?

Tags: developmental-psychology, bias, cognitive-development

I have noticed that young children don't doubt a lot of things. If a teacher tell them "1+1=2", they usually just learn it without questioning. When those children get older, they often start to revisit they old knowledge and start to be skeptic about them.

Would you recommend me some key words for this topic? Thank you.

Comment: 'Naivety', comes to mind. Any more details on why this is not simply a language question? It seems off-topic here as is.

Comment: By key words I mean some psychological theory dealing with this topic, some psychological words (scientific names) describing this phenomenon. I'm not sure if that is a langue question..

Comment: I think child indoctrination is describing this effect.

Comment: Because adults analyze things using existing believes and opinions that they have about the world but with children they're analytical mind hasn't fully developed and also they don't have preexisting believes and opinions about that concept. But this does't mean adults do this, they do it less often.

Comment: They have no basis to question facts yet. They also don't know much about lies, and would not think of a reason someone would lie to them.